# Is there an attribute based font chooser?

Tags: windows, fonts

I like fonts, and I have a lot installed on my computers, but the more I have the harder it is to find the font I am looking for. Is there a website or utility that makes filtering fonts easy?

For example, list all san-serif fonts. Or list serif fonts that support italics and have a narrow typeface. The more attributes that can be combined to filter the better!

Ideally it would be a utility that works with the fonts installed on my system and then provides a preview of custom text in each font face.

Answer (score 2):

There's an interesting [article](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-font-manager.htm) that lists a few

> NexusFont
>   Our rating:8
>   Product type: Runs as a stand-alone program on a user's computer
>
> Pros:
>
> - font preview and categories on the main screen;
> - displays full file properties;
> - view and sort on many attributes;
> - access any font while it is running;
> - many languages
>
> Cons:
>
> - not enough fonts visible at one time in the preview list
>
> Developers website: http://xiles.net
>   Download page: http://xiles.net/downloads/#NexusFont